# API problem for separating Orderers in separate Organizations

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, tls1.2, handshake

I have a hyperledger-fabric project with **3 separate hosts** and **each** host includes **1 Organization**. Each Organization has **2 Peers**, **2 Orderers**, **1 CA Service**(I don't have a separate CA for orderers and all the nodes in each organization get their certificates from the **same CA service**).

All the channels and chaincodes and everything else work correctly. I use an **API service** to communicate with the network, and I can **add users** with API correctly to the network. But the problem is:

**When I'm trying to invoke the chaincode with API, e.g: adding an asset or querying the ledger (submitting and evaluating transactions), the asset will be added after a while(about 20 seconds), but I get the following error:**

```
E1116 07:17:03.978929679       1 ssl_transport_security.cc:1245] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.


2021-11-16T07:17:06.893Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Committer- name: orderer0.org2.example.com:9050, url:grpcs://orderer0.org2.example.com:9050


2021-11-16T07:17:06.894Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server orderer0.org2.example.com:9050 url:grpcs://orderer0.org2.example.com:9050 timeout:3000


2021-11-16T07:17:06.894Z - error: [DiscoveryService]: _buildOrderer[mychannel] - Unable to connect to the discovered orderer orderer0.org2.example.com:9050 due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Committer- name: orderer0.org2.example.com:9050, url:grpcs://orderer0.org2.example.com:9050


E1116 07:17:06.909267625       1 ssl_transport_security.cc:1245] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.


2021-11-16T07:17:09.897Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Committer- name: orderer1.org2.example.com:10050, url:grpcs://orderer1.org2.example.com:10050


2021-11-16T07:17:09.898Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server orderer1.org2.example.com:10050 url:grpcs://orderer1.org2.example.com:10050 timeout:3000


2021-11-16T07:17:09.898Z - error: [DiscoveryService]: _buildOrderer[mychannel] - Unable to connect to the discovered orderer orderer1.org2.example.com:10050 due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Committer- name: orderer1.org2.example.com:10050, url:grpcs://orderer1.org2.example.com:10050


E1116 07:17:09.928123699       1 ssl_transport_security.cc:1245] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.


2021-11-16T07:17:12.901Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Committer- name: orderer0.org3.example.com:11050, url:grpcs://orderer0.org3.example.com:11050


2021-11-16T07:17:12.902Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server orderer0.org3.example.com:11050 url:grpcs://orderer0.org3.example.com:11050 timeout:3000


2021-11-16T07:17:12.902Z - error: [DiscoveryService]: _buildOrderer[mychannel] - Unable to connect to the discovered orderer orderer0.org3.example.com:11050 due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Committer- name: orderer0.org3.example.com:11050, url:grpcs://orderer0.org3.example.com:11050


E1116 07:17:12.952061671       1 ssl_transport_security.cc:1245] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.


2021-11-16T07:17:15.948Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Committer- name: orderer0.org3.example.com:11050, url:grpcs://orderer0.org3.example.com:11050


2021-11-16T07:17:15.949Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server orderer0.org3.example.com:11050 url:grpcs://orderer0.org3.example.com:11050 timeout:3000


2021-11-16T07:17:15.949Z - error: [DiscoveryService]: _buildOrderer[mychannel] - Unable to connect to the discovered orderer orderer0.org3.example.com:11050 due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Committer- name: orderer0.org3.example.com:11050, url:grpcs://orderer0.org3.example.com:11050


E1116 07:17:16.120702832       1 ssl_transport_security.cc:1245] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.
```

Thanks in advance for your help